# Is Mashuah Klaf valid for sta’’m

Tags: halacha, safrus, writing-printing, orach-chaim, klaf-parchment

According to Halacha, are  Sefer Torahs/tefillin/mezuzot with Mashuah Klaf kosher and valid? Or due to the separation between the writing and  the parchment, is it invalid  and unusable for the mitzvah? Is there a difference of opinion regarding this? Mashuah Klaf is a process of preparing smooth parchment by scraping it and putting a past like substance on it, then baking it.

Comment: Practical note: no one manufactures this stuff anymore and any tefillin/mezuza old enough to still be around is certainly already falling apart and invalid anyway for other reasons. The few old Torah that are still floating around are also actively falling apart and are basically worthless since everyone knows it's virtually impossible to fix up. You can offer one for free to most sofrim and they won't take it.